# Can someone please explain to me how this code works?

Tags: javascript

So, a friend shared this code to me about factorials and I kind of am having a hard time understanding how it provides the correct result seeing that it didn't go through a loop. If someone could explain it to me like I'm 5 I'd really appreciate it.

```
function fact(n){
   if(n === 1){
     return 1;
   }else{
     return n * fact(n - 1);
   };
};
console.log(fact(5));
```

Comment: Your Google key word is `recursion`

Comment: It does use a loop; it's recursive. Look up recursion works. This *exact* code has been explained many times over before.

Comment: Does your friend refuse to explain it to you or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the properties of the factorial, `n!` Can be written as `n * (n-1) !`.
That is, the result of the function for n can be obtained as n multiplied by the result of the function for `n-1`, and so on to 1 !:

```
function factorial(n) {
  return (n != 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;
}

alert( factorial(5) ); // 120
```

The recursion basis is the value 1. And you could make the basis and 0. Then the code will be a little shorter:

```
function factorial(n) {
  return n ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;
}

alert( factorial(5) ); // 120
```

In this case, the call `factorial (1)` is reduced to `1 * factorial (0)`, there will be an additional step of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a recursive function call to get the factorial of a number.

```
function fact(n){ // function declaration
   if(n === 1){ //strict type check if n is an integer 1 not a '1'
     return 1; // return back 1
   }else{  // if n is not 1 
     return n * fact(n - 1); //return the number n multiplied by the function call fact again in which the parameter is n-1 now.
   };
};
console.log(fact(5)); //print the result of function call fact(5) and print it to console.
```

```js
function fact(n){
   if(n === 1){
     return 1;
   }else{
     return n * fact(n - 1);
   };
};
console.log(fact(5));
```

It is a call which runs on the mathematical formula to calculate factorial:

```
n * (n-1) !
```

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to recursion you can think of it as a function calling itself; in this case

```
function fact(n){
    //test to see if n is 1, if so just return 1
    if(n === 1)
        return 1;
    // multiply n by the result of calling fact(n-1)
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}

console.log(fact(5));
```

so in this case when you call fact(5) 
you would get 
5 * fact(5-1) = 4 * fact(4-1)= 3 * fact(3-1) = 2 * fact(2-1) = 1

resulting in 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120

it's a bit tricky of a concept to figure out at first, try inserting a console.log into the function to give you a clearer picture of what's going on.

```
function fact(n){
    console.log(n);
    //test to see if n is 1, if so just return 1
    if(n === 1)
        return 1;
    // multiply n by the result of calling fact(n-1)
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a more clearer explanation. Appreciate it.

Comment: No prob one fundamental thing that i should mention about recursion is that every recursive function needs an exit condition, in this example it's the (n===1) return 1; if this exit condition wasn't there then you'd fall into an endless loop.